# Exponential distribution and floor(X)/n

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ is an exponential distribution given by $0$ for $x<0$ and $ae^{-ax}$ for $x\geq 0$

Let $X$ have the exponential distribution. For $n = 1,2, \ldots$ , let $Y_n$ equal $\lfloor X \rfloor/n$. Prove that $Y_n$ is a random variable, and calculate and identify its distribution function.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore $/n$ for now. The r.v. $Z=\lfloor X\rfloor$ has the following pmf (we say pmf because both $Z$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables)
$$
p(z){
=\Pr\{Z=z\}\\=\Pr\{\lfloor X\rfloor=z\}
\\=\Pr\{z\le X<z+1\}
}
$$
I hope the rest of the procedure is straightforward.

**Remark**

The pdf of $X$ must be $-ae^{ax}$ for $x>0$ since $a<0$.